# Counting up from leading zeros python

Tags: python, counting

I'm having a bit of trouble...

So lets say I want to count up like this:

```
000000001
000000002
......[counting up to 9]
000000009
000000010
```

Not sure how you would exactly do this when you're taking in to ac**count** the leading zereos

Comment: That's for strings, and when I try to use that method, [rjust] I get:

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'rjust'

Comment: Even after attempting to convert them into strings, still doesn't work